# Django - HTTP and WebSockets

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-rest-framework, django-socketio

We have an existing large `Django 1.11 & Django-rest-framework` application served by `wsgi`.
We noticed that we might want to use a `WebSocker` for some requests (for example: get all running tasks - live updating)

There is already a GET URL for that: `/api/tasks?running=ture`
So we would like to use same methods and serve this data via WebSocket (Same port is important)

Is it possible? How?

Comment: You want [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for this.

Comment: Wow, I did not know this so far! 
But, is there any `wsgi` supported option?

Comment: I don`t want to change how my application runs (using wsgi)

Comment: I think you will have to look into Autobahn-python if you want wsgi. Disclaimer: I haven't yet used it myself, but am looking into this for my next project